If 'instandgesetzt' is possible as an adjective but not as a verb form, does this mean that 'das Instandsetzen' is also possible?
If so, there seems to be no reason why this should not apply to all such adverbs and even 'Partikeln': written together as compound adjectives or nouns, but left separate as adverbs.

If this is about spelling only, then I think the question would be improved by stating this upfront.

What you assert in the title doesn't make much sense or is simply wrong. What's your question? Please clarify.

According to korrekturen.de 'instand' is not to be written together  with verb forms. If this is unreliable, where do we find definitive answers about Zusammenschreiben??

Although "instandsetzen" is an incorrect spelling, it was commonly used until the German spelling reform of the 1990s, and it is still in use to some extent by people who don't care.
The correct spelling is "instand setzen" or "in Stand setzen", and then the participle becomes "instand gesetzt" or "in Stand gesetzt". However, as you seem to refer to in the question, according to §36 (2.1) of the current Rechtschreibrat rules, the participle can also be written "instandgesetzt" when in use as an adjective.
The noun form is "das Instandsetzen" in any case, because the general rule for nominalisation is that additional parts or supplements of the verb always become part of the noun:

Schach spielen => das Schachspielen
wieder sehen => das Wiedersehen
wild campen => das Wildcampen
ins Wasser springen => das Inswasserspringen (or: das Springen ins Wasser)


My pre-reform Duden (17th edition, 1973) only has instand setzen (which is also used to illustrate R 144a, a rule that applies to forms that are spelt as two words in the infinitive).

@DavidVogt oh, ok -- thanks! Tbh, I just saw the many examples from the Waffengesetz (gun law), a German federal law, in the DWDS corpus, and assumed that they would have known what they were doing back then. Quite dumb of me, knowing what a mess the Waffengesetz is...

"Instandgesetzt" is in fact the Partizip Perfekt of the Verb "instandsetzen". If participles are indeed verbs or adjectives/adverbs (or both) is a different discussion and one I don't want to enter here. Anyway, you can use it as an Adjektiv:

Das instandgesetzte Haus sieht nun viel besser aus.

Regarding writing it together or separated: German composites are written together - unlike English composites, which aren't:

car accident
Autounfall

That some verbs are "separabel", meaning they are separated in some inflected forms doesn't take away from that: "Ich kaufe ein." but the Infinitiv is still einkaufen and not "ein kaufen".
Notice that some words exist in separated as well as non-separated form - with different meanings:

ein viel versprechender Politiker
ein vielversprechender Politiker

The first is a politician who promises much, the second one a very promising politician. Now, perhaps the latter is that because of being the former, but that is a different story. It might not make much difference in politics, but in language it does.
So, to answer your second question: yes "das Instandsetzen" is not only possible, it is also the correct form of this substantivierte Verb.
ADDENDUM: there is in fact a separated form of the verb, which isn't in much use today:

instand setzen

It is a transitive verb (that means it carries an Akkusativobjekt) and means "to enable/empower someone (or something, but it is mostly used for persons) (to do something)" or "to put someone in a position (to do something). For instance:

Ich setze ihn instand, seine Aufgabe zu bewältigen. I make him able to accomplish his task.

The Akkusativobjekt is "ihn" and describes the target of the activity.
Notice that there is a similar difference between the version written apart and the one written together, even if they sometimes overlap. For instance:

Der Motor wird instand gesetzt [...] zu tun.

Maybe its load was lessened, it got another gear box or so. It worked, but was not suited for the task before. Now it will be.

Der Motor wird instandgesetzt.

It (was broken and) will be repaired.

According to korrekturen.de  'instand' is not to be written together with verb forms. Are you saying they are wrong?

@Georg: basically, yes. Again, it is a separable verb, that means: "Ich setze instand". Under the influence of English it is quite modern to write composites separated (one often sees "Sommer Schlussverkauf"), but that doesn't make the practice any more correct.

Yes. In so far as 'instand' can stand alone at the end of a statement, it is tantamount to a 'Partikel', making the official ruling a curious anomaly.
